# How to configure a maximum of 3 pages of an excel file to be printed in python?

Tags: python, excel, winapi, pywin32

I am working with openpyxl and win32.

I have a code that after set some settings, like landscape orientation, print area, etc I print the file, It works very well the only problem I am facing is that I want to print maximum 3 pages regardless of whether the file has 5 or 10 pages, I always want it to print the first 3 pages maximum and I don't know how to do it.

Here is the print code:

```
    # Create an instance of Excel
    excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
    
    # Open the file
    wb = excel.Workbooks.Open(os.path.abspath(excel_file_path))
    
    # Print the file
    wb.PrintOut()
    
    # Quit Excel
    excel.Application.Quit()
    
    print('File ' + excel_file_name + ' successfully printed.')
```

I am expecting to print 3 pages maximum .

Comment: Try `wb.PrintOut(1, 3)`.

Comment: If I do that it print the worksheet1 but not the active one

Comment: First get the appropriate WorkSheet Object from the workbook. Than use the PrintOut(1,3) method.